# Meaning of Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

When I run this code

```
df = raw.copy() # making a copy of dataframe raw
df['new col'] = ''
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['new col'].loc[i] = 'some thing'
```

I got this warning (**warning 1**):

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)
```

Based on user aaossa's suggestion, I changed the code as follows

```
df = raw
df['new col'] = ''
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'new col'] = 'some thing'
```

I then get a similar SettingWithCopyWarning (**warning 2**) with an **added** tip:

```
<ipython-input-74-75e3db22bde6>:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['new col'] = ''
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_single_column(loc, value, pi)
```

The added tip in **warning 2** `Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` came *too late* when I already implemented it (`df.loc[i, 'new col'] = 'some thing'`).

My question are:

1. why wasn't that relevant added tip included in **warning 1**, which would solve the problem at hand and help me to avoid a novice mistake `df = raw` in the second attempt with the modified code?
2. Why was that tip added in **warning 2** when I already implemented (`df.loc[i, 'new col'] = 'some thing'`)?
3. What is `pi` in this **opaque** information `self._setitem_single_column(loc, value, pi)`. What does it mean?

Comment: try `test2 = real_df.copy()`

Comment: You're right: I kept forgetting that basic practice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The warning seems to refer to the operation inside your for loop. Try this instead:

```
df.loc[i, 'new col'] = 'some thing'
```

This statement has the intended effect: it changes the value in the dataframe but it operates directly on the dataframe. When you split the operation (`df['new col'].loc[i]`) you're operating on the view (`df['new col']`) and that's the reason for the warning.

**EDIT:** You should do both, copy your dataframe and use `.loc`

```py
test2 = real_df.copy()
for i in range(len(test2)):
    test2.loc[i, 'b'] = 5
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code will make more 4 columns with the names of `(i, b)`as shown by this toy example ```test = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
test['b'] = ''
for i in range(len(test)):
    test[i, 'b'] = 5```

Comment: You're right @Nemo , I forgot to add `.loc`. I've updated my answer

Comment: Your answer solved my original problem but I changed the scope of the OP. Appreciate your help though.